# FileSystemWatcher Events Not Firing C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lVormV8cb8

But my FileSystemWatcher events don't appear to firing. Any idea why?

ps. My knowledge of C# and the Windows API is very primitive - please take that into account with any responses.

Window1.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.IO;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string watchedFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE"), "Pictures");

            FileSystemWatcher fsw = new FileSystemWatcher(watchedFolder);

            MainWindow.Title = "Monitoring: " + fsw.Path;

            fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

            fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);

            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        void fsw_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            updatedImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(
                    delegate ()
                    {
                        ImageSourceConverter isc = new ImageSourceConverter();
                        updatedImage.Source = (ImageSource)isc.ConvertFromString(e.FullPath);
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Window1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="updatedImage" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your XAML is missing of a critical piece.
The binding of the MainWindow_Loaded event handler.
No code is binded to that event, thus no FileSystemWatcher is created, and initialized.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="525"
        Name="MainWindow"
        Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded">
```